# Git bash tab completion for .sh files

Tags: git, msysgit, msys

I'm using msysgit on windows 7 and I found bash scripting very useful. I wrote some .sh scripts, but I'd like git bash to autocomplete their names. For now I can see, that after initial prompt git bash autocompletes only .exe, .bat and .com files. How can I allow autocompletion for .sh files?

Comment: No experience using git under Windows, but what shell are you using?

Comment: The one shipped with msysgit. I think it is bash shell.

Comment: Try without put extension. That's all are shell script. in Program Files x86 / Git / libexec / git-core

Comment: It doesn't work. As I wrote, tab-completion works now for .exe, .com, .bat files.

Comment: I would take a look at the docs for MingW - what msysgit uses.

Answer (score 27):

I found out that files with #!/bin/sh as first line are autocompleted. It's enough for me.

Comment: Wow! You are my superhero!

Comment: Of course, #!/bin/sh. It worked for me, so I have done it right :-)